# What is the actual purpose of using new Guid() in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

I am learning about GUID in C#. While reading, I have come across these two things such as

```
1. Guid obj = new Guid();
2. Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();
```

I read, the first one always be 16 byte with all 0. The second one will makes an actual GUID with a unique value. Then What is the actual purpose of new Guid();? And When to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938151/guid-newguid-vs-new-guid

This is repeated.

Comment: Then When to use new Guid();? Can anyone place the answer for this?

Comment: `Guid()` is a default constructor, since it is not taking any parameters, it will give default value which is `Guid.Empty`.

Comment: @thevan From [Jon Hanna answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11938280/447156): In all, `new Guid()` isn't that useful due to this lack of clarity, **but it's not possible to have a value-type that doesn't have a parameterless constructor that returns an all-zeros-and-nulls value**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Guid` is a value type. The compiler accepts `new T()` for all value types `T`, with exactly the same meaning as `default(T)`. A value type cannot prevent this even if `default(T)` is a nonsensical value for this specific type.

So, to answer your question, `new Guid()` isn't allowed because it's useful, it's allowed for technical reasons only. You shouldn't ever use it. If you really want an all-zero `Guid`, `default(Guid)` or `Guid.Empty` are far better for readability.

Answer (score 0):

> Then What is the actual purpose of new Guid();?

`new Guid()` willbe used to intialise the `Guid` object by calling the constructor.

there is a static method `NewGuid()` in `GUID` structure which will return you the actual `GUID` by calling `Guid.NewGuid()`

Answer (score 0):

I guess the purpose is NOT the parameterless constructor, but the constructor overloads taking an existing GUID.

There are also several cases where you need a parameterless constructor like for deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at GUID implementation here:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/guid.cs#b622ef5f6b76c10a

Like already said, it is structural type and needs to have default value.