# How do I generate a new GUID and then write to a new file in a specified path, using that GUID as the filename?

Tags: c#, .net

I have created a Scanner application  using C# in visual studio.I am trying to directly save the scan data in GUIDs as the file name

How do I generate a new GUID and then write to a new file in a specified path, using that GUID as the filename?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hi , Welcome to stack overflow  .Please take the time to read to see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
var somepath = Path.GetTempPath(); // tempFolder if you want it
var fileName = Path.Combine(somepath,$"{Guid.NewGuid()}.dat");

// Do something with your file name
```

Add pepper and salt to taste

---

**Additional resources**

[Path.Combine Method](http://Path.Combine%20Method)

> Combines strings into a path.

[Guid.NewGuid Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Initializes a new instance of the Guid structure.

Example

```
public static void Main()
{
    Guid g;
    // Create and display the value of two GUIDs.
    g = Guid.NewGuid();
    Console.WriteLine(g);
    Console.WriteLine(Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

**Output**

```
0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e
7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7
```

Comment: @RaviKumar dont forget to mark an answer as correct, so other people can benefit form the question

Answer (score 0):

the Guid type has a Guid.NewGuid() method that generates a 'random' guid.

also check out this post that discusses pros and cons of newing up a guid type v using the built in newguid().

[Guid.NewGuid() vs. new Guid()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938151/guid-newguid-vs-new-guid)